# Why do green colored rectangles appear on the view finder around light-sources that are in the view?

Tags: viewfinder

I have a point-and-shoot camera and when I point it at a view to take a picture, green-colored rectangles appear on the view-finder around any light-sources in the view.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Information about the camera model is probably going to help, though I suspect it's to highlight areas that will be over exposed or blown. Your manual probably has the information.

Comment: JoanneC: Thank you. The camera is a Sony Cybershot N50 digital camera. I will look up its manual.

Comment: Sony eSupport does not recognize the model number.

Comment: Are they rectangles that go right to the edge of the frame? Or do they just box around the bright object.  Also is the box filled or just an outline?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely a putting a box around any over-exposed areas.  The more conventional approach to this is to shade any area that is overexposed, but putting a box around the area can work too.  The reason for this is to highlight areas where image data will be lost.

Comment: Sony uses green squares (outlined, not filled) to show where the camera found a face. Perhaps this feature is malfunctioning? But if those are rectangles, as said by OP, it would still be quite an odd way to warn about possibility of blown highlights. In my Sony they use blinking black color on blown out areas, but that's after taking a photo, not a warning beforehand.